# Is there a way to transfer an entire array at the same time across a serial connection from Processing to the Arduino IDE?

Tags: c++, arduino, processing, multitasking

The current project I am involved in requires data from 20 different buttons in a user interface on Processing, to be transferred to an Arduino Uno for the purpose of controlling 5 different channels each with 4 different modes corresponding to the buttons. Currently, each button works; however, I have noticed that the baud rate effects how well each button works and it seems as if the farther down each section of code for each button is, the worse it functions. Right now I am implementing a byte array that is sent through the serial connection and constantly read by the microcontroller. Each of the 5 channels looks only at one index of the array and updates it based on the mode that corresponds with the buttons. Is there an efficient and easy way to do large-scale multitasking, with arrays, through a serial connection?

```
////////ARDUINO

    void serialRead()
{
  if(Serial.available())
  {
    int incomingValue = Serial.read();

    values[currentValue] = incomingValue;

    currentValue++;

    if(currentValue > 4)
    {
      currentValue = 0;
    }

   /////////torso

    if(incomingValue == 65 || 66 ||67 || 68 || 69 || 70 || 71 || 72)
    {
      values[0] = incomingValue;
    }

   /////////shoulders

    if(incomingValue == 73 || 74 ||75 || 76 || 77 || 78 || 79 || 80)
    {
      values[1] = incomingValue;
    }
    /////////Arms

    if(incomingValue == 81 || 82 || 83 || 84 || 85 || 86 || 87 || 88)
    {
      values[2] = incomingValue;
    }

   /////////Hands

    if(incomingValue == 89 || 90 || 97 || 98 || 99 || 100 || 101 || 102)
    {
      values[3] = incomingValue;
    }

   /////////Neck

    if(incomingValue == 103 || 104 || 105 || 106 || 107 || 108 || 109 || 110)
    {
      values[4] = incomingValue;
    }
  }
}

///////PROCESSING

void draw(){ // graphics and functions of program 

  byte out[] = new byte[5];
  out[0] = byte(torso);
  out[1] = byte(shoulder);
  out[2] = byte(arm);
  out[3] = byte(hand);
  out[4] = byte(neck);
  myPort.write(out);

///under each button, the corresponding char is assigned to torso, shoulder,etc.
///they are then converted into their corresponding byte formats and sent through serial
```

Comment: `incomingValue == 65 || 66 ||67 || 68 || 69 || 70 || 71 || 72` That's not how you compare a variable to multiple values. Where are you people getting this syntax? And you want to compare it to a range anyway.

Comment: You are also rewriting values in the array. First you write to the next index (`currentValue`), then you write it to an index based on the value (`incomingValue`).

Comment: I thought the syntax was a simplified version of writing "incomingValue == 66 || incomingValue == 67 || ... " but I guess not. I will change that.

Comment: And can you clarify how I am rewriting values? The only purpose for (currentValue) is to constantly receive values from Processing and allocate them. It is rewriting the values but they have already been assigned to their specific indices and sent to the control function before the next value comes in.

Comment: sounds like you are transmitting a lot of unnecessary data - maybe you should consider only sending changes instead of transmitting the whole array, you could e.g. send a pair of bytes one telling what button and then to what state. checkout the observer pattern for ideas around this type of handling

Answer (score 1):

Try writing this:

```
if(incomingValue == 65 || 66 ||67 || 68 || 69 || 70 || 71 || 72)
```

Like this instead:

```
if(incomingValue >= 65 && incomingValue <= 72)
```